# In Rally UI how to find all user stories that do *not* have a parent?

Tags: rally

How do I find all user stories that do *not* have a parent? I want to ensure that my team is associating user stories with a feature so that the % feature complete is accurate.

The user story "query" UI doesn't allow this.

So far I tried adding the following queries to my dashboard widget with “Type = User Story”.

User stories without parent user stories
(Parent = null)

User stories that don't have parents, but they are not portfolio items
((PortfolioItem = null) AND (Parent = null))

User stories that do not have parents…
((PortfolioItem = null) OR (Parent = null))

Use stories without a parent
(Parent.FormattedID = null)

All of the above still return user stories *with* parents.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just loose stories (no feature parent, no story parent) then your middle query should be right...

```
((PortfolioItem = null) AND (Parent = null))
```

I tried adding that in the query setting section in a custom list and added the Parent and Feature columns in the column picker and I didn't get any data back that had either of those fields populated.  Is that what you're doing?  Or what data are you getting back that seems wrong?

Comment: Yes, this works. I added the above to the custom list and got what I wanted.